# How to use WHERE in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to use `WHERE` in Eloquent ? I need to do something like this:

```
if ($params) {
    foreach ($params as $param => $value)
        $this->users->where($param, '=', $value);
}

$users = $this->users->get($values)->take($limit)->toArray();
```

P.S.
`$this->users` is the instance of model extended by  `Eloquent`

Comment: You need `whereIn`, not `where`, judging by your example.

Comment: @N.B. `whereIn` is `OR` type, while what OP has here is `AND`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ - you are correct about the difference in `where` and `in`, but incorrect in what the OP *needs* as he only showed fragment of the logic and code.

Comment: No, I'm positive. OPs code 'does' `AND` wheres, it's just wrong in terms of API. Check also accepted answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Initiate your query.
2. Append the where to your query.
3. Finished your query (`take`, `get`, `toArray`)

> ```
> $query = $this->users->newQuery();
>
> if ($params) {
>     foreach ($params as $param => $value)
>         $query = $query->where($param, $value);
> }
>
> $query = $query->take($limit)->get($values)->toArray();
>
> dd($query);
> ```

Comment: `take` doesn't 'finish' the query, neither does `toArray`. `take` sets limit to the query, while `toArray` is a collection (and model) method, so can be called only after the query has been executed. And to execute you need `get`/`find`/`first` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Seeing your code I would say you need whereIn, see the docs for clarification.
See also, http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

You can use the where clause as in:

```
$model = User::where('$param', '=', $something)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your Eloquent Object before using `get()` function.

Logic steps:

1. Create Eloquent Object
2. Call all conditional/limits/joins functions
3. Fetch your rows using `get()`.

Hence, Your Code will be as follows:

```
$users = $this->users;
if ($params) {
    foreach ($params as $param => $value)
        $users->where($param, '=', $value);
}

$usersResult = $users->take($limit)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this:

```
$query->where($params);

// instead of
foreach ($params as $param => $value)
        $query = $query->where($param, $value);
}
```